# Deploying .Net Core 2.0 App Includes 150+ Dlls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, webdeploy

I recently updated my Visual Studio version from 2017 to 2019 also installing the .net core version 2.2. I had .Net Core 2.0 web projects which only contained the dlls that were added through out the Nudget packaging system which looks like this;

[image: Correct Folder Structure]

This folder contains only 22 items.

But after the VS update when I publish the application I have an output folder which looks like this;

[image: False Folder Structure]

This folder contains almost 200 dlls. I did not even change the publishing settings. I do not have any of these dependencies, and I am making sure that the deployment method is not `self-contained deployment` but `Framework-dependent Deployment`

I am using the CLI command to publish my application;

> dotnet publish -c Release

What is the reason I have this many dlls on my published folder ?

Edit:

Here is how my .csproj file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AstrodyneTdi.Web" Version="3.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.0.0-rtm-alpha4" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.6.9" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I would have guessed that it was set as a self-contained deployment, as you stated. Just making sure, is your "PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest" set to true?

Comment: @Jordan I do not mention that flag in my .csproj file. I updated my question to show how it looks like.

Comment: Hmm, okay I added an answer as it was too wordy for a comment. I'm guessing that's not the issue for you though. That's all I got, good luck either way : )

Comment: @Jordan interestingly it did work! For some reason upgrading it to VS 2019 required me to place that flag into my .csproj file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me I had to add this section to the .csproj file a while ago, specifically PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest

[MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-store)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>true</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
```